# regex_replace, replace whole word only

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have the following rows in my PostgreSQL table:

```
kpi_old
---------------------------------
Other operating exp (1200)
Other operating exp (1400)
Other operating exp (1600)
Other operating expenses 0 (1200)
Other operating expenses 0 (1400)
Other operating expenses 0 (1600)
```

I would like to replace:

- `Other operating exp` => `Other operating expenses & taxes`
- `Other operating expenses 0` => `Other operating expenses & taxes`

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
"kpi_old",
regexp_replace("kpi_old", '(Other operating exp)','Other operating expenses & taxes') as "kpi_new"
```

The problem is, it returns the following:

```
Other operating expenses & taxes (1200)
Other operating expenses & taxes (1400)
Other operating expenses & taxes (1600)
Other operating expenses & taxesenses 0 (1200)
Other operating expenses & taxesenses 0 (1400)
Other operating expenses & taxesenses 0 (1600)
```

Which regex can I use to replace the exact match in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use optional group `(enses)?`

```
=# select regexp_replace('Other operating expenses 0 (1600)', '(Other operating exp(enses)?)', 'Other operating expenses & taxes');
              regexp_replace               
-------------------------------------------
 Other operating expenses & taxes 0 (1600)
(1 row)

=# select regexp_replace('Other operating exp (1600)', '(Other operating exp(enses)?)', 'Other operating expenses & taxes');
             regexp_replace              
-----------------------------------------
 Other operating expenses & taxes (1600)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a pattern that covers both:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
          kpi_old,
          'Other operating exp(enses 0)?',
          'Other operating expenses & taxes'
       )
FROM mytab;

             regexp_replace              
-----------------------------------------
 Other operating expenses & taxes (1200)
 Other operating expenses & taxes (1400)
 Other operating expenses & taxes (1600)
 Other operating expenses & taxes (1200)
 Other operating expenses & taxes (1400)
 Other operating expenses & taxes (1600)
(6 rows)
```